# Python: efficiently generating a vector with different values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm programming a scientific application in Python, and the performance of my algorithm so far is terrible. I'm trying to find an efficient way to code what I'm doing. Basically, I have to multiply

```
 def get_thing(self, chi, n):

    return np.sum(self.an[n][j] * pow(chi, -j) for j in xrange(1, self.j))
```

where `self.an[i][j]` is a previously generated array. Then I'll have to do this:

```
 pot = np.sum(self.coeffs[n] * self.get_thing(chi, n) for n in xrange(0, self.n))
```

where `chi` changes and cannot be cached, as it's a point that is being generated outside this class. Of course, this is extremely slow and not very bright. How can I improve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `get_things` you could certainly simplify things as something like:

```
def get_thing(self, chi, n):

    return np.sum(self.an[n,1:self.j] * np.power(chi,-np.arange(1,self.j)))
```

Note, that you don't want to index numpy arrays using [i][j] notation; instead use [i,j].

You may be able to make further improvements using higher level broadcasting as @eat suggested.

**Edit:** 
Made a couple of changes to the above code to try to get the indexing to match the OP and changed a sign error in my code.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that chi is not a vector, and is generated for each new run function call.

Comment: @Ivan if `chi` is a single float, then `y = np.power(chi,x)` where `x` is an array will produce an array where the ith element of `y`, y_i = chi^x_i. This is a numpy broadcasting feature. The code that I provided should be equivalent to the `get_thing` you originally wrote, but much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, try to do the computations in higher level of abstraction, i.e. try to avoid python level looping.

Study carefully how to do element-wise operations and how [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operates, and last but not least don't forget the power of `linear algebra`!